# Cross validation within a bootstrap sample: is leakage a problem here?

Tags: cross-validation, inference, bootstrap, lasso, data-leakage

I would like to calculate the sampling distribution for logistic LASSO coefficients. One approach to calculating this sampling distribution is described on page 143 of "Statistical Learning with Sparsity" by Hastie, Tibshirani and Wainwright, which is freely available [here](https://hastie.su.domains/StatLearnSparsity_files/SLS.pdf).

Briefly, in section 6.2 the authors advocate applying 10-fold cross validation to bootstrapped data.

In more detail, the authors suggest (as I understand it) that we should resample the original data with replacement, and that for each bootstrap sample $(\boldsymbol{X}^*_b, \boldsymbol{y}^*_b)$ we:

1. Fit a lasso path to ($\boldsymbol{X}^*_b, \boldsymbol{y}^*_b$) over a dense grid of values $\Lambda = \{\lambda_l\}_{l=1}^{L}$.
2. Divide the training samples into 10 groups at random.
3. With the $k^{th}$ group left out, fit a LASSO path to the remaining 9/10ths, using
   the same grid $\Lambda$.
4. For each $\lambda \in \Lambda$ compute the mean-squared prediction error for the left-out
   group.
5. Average these errors to obtain a prediction error curve over the grid $\Lambda$.
6. Find the value $\hat{\lambda}^*_{CV,b}$ that minimizes this curve, and then return the coefficient
   vector from our original fit in step (1) at that value of $\lambda$, which gives us $\hat{\beta}^*_b(\hat{\lambda}^*_{CV,b})$.

Repeat steps 1-6 a large number of times (e.g. $B$ = 1000), to get the set of bootstrapped LASSO estimators $\{\hat{\beta}^*_b(\hat{\lambda}^*_{CV,b})\}^B_{b=1}$, which gives us our desired sampling distribution.

**My question**

I'm confused about step 2. We are dividing the bootstrap sample into 10 folds, but since the bootstrap sample was created by replacement sampling, identical observations may show up in both the training *and* the testing folds. Doesn't this lead to leakage?

Notes:

- I get that such leakage would lead to the MSE being optimistic for all $\Lambda$, but it's not clear to me that this would be order-preserving (i.e. that the best-performing $\lambda$ with leakage is the best-performing $\lambda$ without it).
- The authors mention in a footnote "On a technical note, we implement the bootstrap with observation weights $w^{*}_i = k/N$, with $k = 0, 1, 2, . . .$. In cross-validation, the units are again the original $N$ observations, which carry along with them their weights $w^{*}_i$". Is this done to, and does it, prevent leakage?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good question. Would you get much different results with grouped sampling, using the original row id as grouping variable?

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelM. Do you mean use the original row index when assigning to CV folds? For example, suppose our bootstrap sample consists of {(2,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,0),(2,0)}, with corresponding original row indexes, say, {1,1,2,3,4}. Running two-fold CV (assigned by original row index) might give fold1 = {(2,1),(2,1),(4,0)} and fold2 = {(3,1),(2,0)}. In this case, my folds would differ in size, so I would weigh the MSE as mean_MSE_b_lambda = MSE_fold1_{b,lambda}*(3/5)+MSE_fold2_{b,lambda}*(2/5) (i.e. weight would be proportional to size of test fold). Does this resemble what you had in mind?

Comment: Almost. But instead of weighing, all rows with the same original row id will go in the same fold.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelM. So recycling my above example, where the bootstrap sample consists of {(2,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,0),(2,0)}, I already have original row IDs in the same fold: fold1 = {(2,1),(4,0)} and fold2 = {(3,1),(2,0)} --- which have corresponding rows IDs {1,1,3} in fold1 and {2,4} in fold2. (Note: in my made-up example, my bootstrap sample just happened to draw from the first four rows of the original data.) So what do you propose I do differently? I don't want to drop the duplicate observation in fold1 because then I would effectively be sampling the original data *without* replacement.

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. My second comment was quite rubbish! Your original suggestion seems as I had in mind, although one typically would not reweight the performance scores to adjust for unequal sized folds and just take a plain average. I think we could argue pro and con weighting.

Comment: OK great, thank you! I'm just going repost an excerpt from my last comment as there was a typo (I omitted the duplicate observation in fold1):

"I already have original row IDs in the same fold: fold1 = {(2,1),**(2,1)**,(4,0)} and fold2 = {(3,1),(2,0)}"

Thanks again.